# GestureDedector's onTap event not working for Sizedbox

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test, flutter-widget, flutter-card

I've got a problem with onTap event for GestureDedector.
I tried in card too but not working. When I tap sizedbox nothing happens.

```
      GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => GoToPage(),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: Card(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.asset(
                                "assets/png/icon2.png",
                                width: 64.0,
                              ),
                              ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Nagual sizedbox works, stackoverflow asked me to shorten it when asking the question. SizedBox properties:
width: 146.0,
height: 170.0,

Comment: Where are you testing it, web or phone device.  On web, it is working fine.

Comment: On mobile device not working. Even property of GestureDedector I've tried it with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add behavior property of GestureDetector

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: (){},
),
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to specify GestureDetector behaviour

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onTap: (){},
),
```

Answer (score 2):

By default a GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches, this behavior can be controlled with behavior.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures